# Stop further randomisation with flask paginate

Tags: python, mysql, pagination

I've created a demo website which queries a database and then paginates the results. The user might want to set the results to be returned in a random order. The problem I have is that if the user chooses the random option, when they start to click through the results pages, the results are randomised for each page which causes a repetition of the returned results. Is there a simple way to stop this happening?
The randomisation is done as part of the sql query i.e order by rand(). If you want to see what I mean, the website is namelessfashion.co.uk

Comment: The only chance that i see you have 2 more columns, and you save in one column the pages you already processed and the second colmun has all used ids so far seperated by comma and by another diverder, so that you can use this information to exclude the ids from the resultseet. So if you cann  page number 2 you exlude all from page 1..... needs somewhat finetuning, but it should work.

Comment: Yeah that might be a way around it. I wasn't sure if there was a pagination setting I was missing or something. Thanks!